# Using Sliding window to extract features in a large dataset

Tags: python, sliding-window

Suppose I have a dataset with a timestamp column. I have given a midtime points vector say (20, 30, 40). I want a moving window using conditions: (midpoint-overlap) to (midpoint+overlap) where overlap = 5. Now, select the corresponding values of the moving window timepoints and calculate the mean of those values. How can I write a function in python? Anyone can help me, please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: SO is not a Homework Service

Comment: mid = np.array([1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5])
s1=mid-0.5
s2=mid+0.5
mean=[]
for i in range(len(mid)):
    y = d.loc[(d['time']>=s1[i]) & (d['time']<=s2[i])]
    n = np.mean(y.iloc[:,1:])
    mean.append(n)

Here I am giving you an idea. My dataset is very large. I want to avoid for loop. is there any another way to do this?